# Error setting layout params to ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I'm having issues trying to set `layoutparams` to an `ImageView` created programmatically:

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(gallerySize.x, gallerySize.y));
```

The imageView is inside an `LinearLayout`, and I think that should work, but I get this error:

```
09-30 10:33:24.450: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5418): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
```

Maybe, the fact that this imageView Activity is configured to use an different layout for portrait and landscape view (I'm using this with an different copy of xml layout inside the layout-land folder). When it's in portrait view the problematic code line isn't executed, instead I execute the following line:

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(gallerySize.x, gallerySize.y));
```

I tried to keep this line unchanged, but then I get the error:

```
09-30 10:49:47.450: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5760): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Gallery$LayoutParams
```

The main difference in the portrait and landscape layout, is that portrait uses a `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation and have an `Gallery` widget (that uses that imageView), while the problematic landscape uses horizontal orientation and `ListView` instead of `Gallery`.

I'm kind lost here, any tips will be appreciated.

---

EDITED

The imageView is implemented in this class:

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

            Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(appFolder+"/"+imagesPath[position]);
            //productImages[position] = temp;

            imageView.setImageBitmap(temp);

            if(landscape)
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(gallerySize.x, gallerySize.y));
            else
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(gallerySize.x, gallerySize.y));


            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

            return imageView;
        }
    }
```

And the ImageAdapter instance is used here:

```
    public onCreate(...) {
        ...
        if(!landscape) {
        Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.infoproduto.gallery);
        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    setSelectedImage(position);
                }
            }); 
        }
        else {
        ListView galleryLView = (ListView) findViewById(R.infoproduto.galleryLView);
        galleryLView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        galleryLView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    setSelectedImage(position);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you want change the size of an image by using LayoutParams

Comment: PLease show code where you add the imageview.

Comment: @surendra Yeah, if I don't use an fixed size the images will be really big for an 'gallery'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured out the solution, it was so obvious!

The ImageView is used inside ImageAdapter, and this ImageAdapter is setted as adapter in an ListView instance:

```
    ListView galleryLView = (ListView) findViewById(R.infoproduto.galleryLView);
    galleryLView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

So Instead using LinearLayout.LayoutParams (that is the only layout in my xml file), i used ListView.LayoutParams and it works perfectly!